# GAS GMailApp.createDraft() fails even with proper authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, gmail, authorization

I'm writing an Apps Script library for spreadsheets that creates a separate onEdit installable trigger for each user (via a menu item).

In the onEdit callback I check that `activeUser == effectiveUser` to make sure the script only runs for a particular user via their own trigger (there's one edit trigger for each user, and they all get triggered by anyone's edits).

I check that the script has been properly authorized with `ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL).getAuthorizationStatus()`.

Still, for **some users** `GMailApp.createDraft()` always fails (returns `null`), though it's called with the `from` parameter = `null` (meaning to use the effective user's account). For other users (me) `createDraft()` always succeeds.

The relevant oAuth scopes are included in BOTH the library script AND the spreadsheet doc:

```
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose"
```

What is going on here? Why would `GMailApp.createDraft()` fail when the script/library has been properly authorized?
Is there any way to find out why it's failing?

Comment: By fail you mean it throws a 403 error?

Comment: @JoseVasquez - GMailApp.createDraft() returns null - it does not create the draft.

Comment: When using [getEffectiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser) `If the script is running under an installable trigger, this returns the account of the user who created the trigger`. It'd be helpful if you share the script you are running (without sensitive data).